# Why is my web server converting spaces to underscores, but running from command prompt doesn't?

Tags: php, iis, iis-8, shortcut-file

I made an intranet page that allows me to easily manage my quicklaunch icons in Windows.  I wanted to be able to drag-sort them and on new boxes, easily deploy them.  Worked great, until I ran into a weird snag.  If a shortcut's target has spaces, it changes the spaces to underscores.  In the process of debugging, I made a simple makeshortcut.php with it all hardcoded:

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shortcut = $shell->CreateShortcut("\\\\solenth\\ql$\\017 - AutoHotKey - Primary.lnk");
$shortcut->TargetPath = "p:\\misc\\ahk\\AutoHotKey - Primary.ahk";
$shortcut->Arguments = "";
$shortcut->IconLocation = "p:\\misc\\ahk\\AutoHotKey_Blue.ico";
$shortcut->Description = "AutoHotKey";
$shortcut->WorkingDirectory = "p:\\misc\\ahk";
echo $shortcut->TargetPath;
$shortcut->save();
```

When I run it via makeshortcut.php in my browser, I see:
P:\misc\ahk\AutoHotKey_-_Primary.ahk

If I open cmd and change into the webserver's folder and run it, I see:
P:\misc\ahk\AutoHotKey - Primary.ahk

Any idea why the web server is replacing spaces with underscores?  At first I said "ahh, my workstation's PHP installation is not the same as the web server" but I then RDP'd into the webserver and went to the PHP folder that is used by the server and ran the script, and it still worked fine.  So it's only when actually ran from the web that it does this.

I'm perplexed.  Any suggestions?

Update: I just had an idea.  I made a C# console app that creates a shortcut.  Hardcoded as in the PHP.  I run it in the command prompt, works.  I call exec to run it from PHP and it does the same underscore thing.  Now I'm really flummoxed.

OS: Server 2012 R2
PHP: 8.3.1
Web Server: IIS 8

Comment: Two things you should notice: 1) Windows Server 2012 reached end of life. 2) PHP on IIS is community supported only, https://docs.phpmanager.xyz/getting-started/supported-platforms Hope there is still someone to answer such questions.

Comment: I definitely noticed #1; you'd have to be crazy to think 2012 is still supported :)   I just can't afford $1500 or whatever for 2022. As for #2, I'm thinking now that it's more an IIS issue than PHP since the C# program also did it.  Well, I guess though I'm still calling that C# from PHP.  I should install .NET and call it from there to test.

Hmm I suppose it DOES lead back to potentially a 2012 problem since IIS is also old as it came with that old OS.  I guess I should look for a demo or something of 2022 and test it.  I wish they had a budget program for non business users.

Thanks

Comment: Well I'll be buggered.  I just realized rather than go to the hassle of installing 2022 in a VM or something, I'll turn on IIS that comes with Windows 10.  I copied my site over and configured to run locally, tested, and sure enough it works perfectly.  Doesn't create the underscores.

So I guess it is something wonky with IIS 8!  Thanks Lex Li for reminding me of how old it is, I wouldn't have really thought about that as an issue before :)

Comment: You can write that as an answer below and accept it.

Comment: If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, please post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept it so that future readers can learn from you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain exactly why it happens, but Lex Li's comment about how old Server 2012 R2 is made me think well, maybe it is related to age.  So I made a VM and installed a modern server OS with newer IIS and the problem resolved itself.

Now since it could be any number of things that are different between the two servers, but the application itself is the exact same.  So while I cannot definitively point to old IIS as a problem, I'd recommend if having the same problem under 2012 to test your app on a newer platform instead.